# Jersey: How to bypass all filters and resource matching?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a jersey application which contains some pre-matching filters, post-matching filters, as well as some resource mappings.

Now I have a black list of urls, I'd like these urls to return 404 as soon as possible. (bypass my pre-matching filters)

Is there a way of doing this?

1 option I can come up with is to create a pre-matching filter with highest order to do the blacklist check and throw special exception like BlackListException. And at the same time, register an exception mapper to handle this BlacklistException.

I'm just wondering is there any better way of doing this.

Thanks

Leon

Comment: A servlet filter would be called even earlier. Even before the request enters the Jersey application.

Comment: Servlet filter helps, but isn't jaxrs an independent spec? I saw some articles about running jersey on Netty rather than servlet containers like jetty/tomcat. If there's a pure JAXRS/jersey way to do this, that would be better.

Comment: Yeah, your `@PreMatching` filter with priority is your best bet then.

Comment: _"but isn't jaxrs an independent spec"_ - JAX-RS, no. Jersey, yes. JAX-RS specification is built around the servlet container. The specification states that any other deployment (like in a SE runtime) would be implementation specific. So Jersey supports other deployments, but if you are sticking to the JAX-RS spec, then you are only running in a serlvet container.